# Extending NKIssue - NewsStandKit (iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, newsstand-kit

I'm developing a new magazine app using `NewsStandKit` and I need to extend `NKIssue` because my issues have more properties. But i don't know how to do that and store these new properties at the `NewsStand` content library. I searched in Google, StackOverflow, etc. this question but I didn't find anything. Can anyone tell me how to do that or another solution for my problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't store data directly on the NKIssue object itself. NKIssue has a contentURL property that is unique for each issue, and points to a writable path that you can use to store your content. How you store it (plist, sqlite db, flat files) is up to you.

You could subclass or add a category on NKIssue to make accessing your app-specific properties easier, but it's still up to you to determine how they are stored on disk.